# Functional equation regarding differentiability

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

How do you solve this problem ? I'm more interested in the method than the result .
Find all the differentiable functions that satisfy the following condition : f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your function is differentiable then $f'(x)=f'(y)$ for all $x,y$ (just differentiate two sides of the equation w.r.t. $x$). Therefore:
$$
f'(x)=k
$$ 
for some constant $k$ and therefore $f(x)=kx+c$ and with substitution in the original equation, we can see $c=0$.

Answer (score 0):

The solutions are $f(x)=c\cdot x$ for any constant $c\in\mathbb R$. This is solved using the [Cauchy equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation). When $f:\mathbb Q\to \mathbb Q$, we can prove this without using the differentiability (or continuity or any other kind of 'smoothness'). (Then, however, $c\in\mathbb Q$.)

Answer (score 0):

If your function is differentiable then it is continuous. Note $f(0) = 0$. You can furthermore prove that for any $c$ and any rational $q$, you have $f(qc) = qf(c)$.  If $f(c) \neq c f(1)$ for some $c$, then note $c \neq 0$ and so then you can prove that the function is not continuous at $1$ by taking rational multiples of $c$ that are arbitrarily close to $1$ to get a sequence of values $x_n$ that converges to $1$ but for which $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(x_n) \neq f(1)$. So your function has the form $f(c) = f(1) \cdot c$ if it is continuous, and in particular, if it is differentiable.